# Specify always to GnuPG sign uploads of a distribution to PyPI

Tags: python, digital-signature, software-distribution

The [Distutils `upload` command](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/packageindex.html#the-upload-command), which uploads the distribution to PyPI, can specify to first sign the distribution and upload that signature:

> You can use the `--sign` option to tell *upload* to sign each uploaded file
>   using GPG (GNU Privacy Guard) […] You can also specify which key to use for
>   signing using the `--identity=name` option.

How can I specify that, for a particular distribution, every upload should be signed with a particular key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Distutils commands can be [configured with a `setup.cfg` file](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/configfile.html), by putting option values in a section named for the command.

So, to specify `sign` and `identity` options for the `upload` command, write in the distribution's `setup.cfg` file:

```
[upload]

# Sign distributions, and upload the signing public key?
sign = true

# Which GnuPG identity to use for signing?
identity = christina@example.org
```